# spritekit - SKEmitterNode particle scale, coords, etc with ipad vs iphone

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, sprite-kit, skemitternode

When I use SKEmitterNode in a universal app, i want my particle effects to look the same regardless of screen size.

I noticed when i use the particle editor, my particle effects will be half size on a retina ipad.  In my code I have to resort to doing this.

```
self.shipFlame.particleScale = convertNum(self.shipFlame.particleScale)
self.shipFlame.particleSpeed = convertNum(self.shipFlame.particleSpeed)
self.shipFlame.particleSpeedRange = convertNum(self.shipFlame.particleSpeedRange)
```

convertNum is a function that just checks if we're on an ipad or not, and doubles the number accordingly.  Is there any nicer way of accomplishing this?  What's the point of having a nice sks file if I have to set a bunch of variables manually?

Comment: What's the particle texture? I would assume the effect scales with the texture, so if there's a @2x or ~ipad@2x texture for the effect it might just scale correctly.

Comment: its just the default spark.png thats created when you make an SKS file.. should i be adding a @2x at the end of the name?  I am just using the default image that xcode creates

Comment: did you find a solution?